# Jquery Toggle Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, hidden

How would I go about hiding the select element and whenever I click the button it would get displayed and when I click it again it would hide it? So far I have the following code It seems to not be working as I expected it to. I know toggle is probably the method in solving this problem in jquery.

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type='button' name='button' id='testbtn' value='Test Button' />
<br>
<select style="visibility:hidden" id='List' name='List'/>
</form>

$("#testbtn").click(function() {
   $('#List').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Lots of right answers thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change visibility:hidden to display:none.  JQuery toggles the display attribute.

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type='button' name='button' id='testbtn' value='Test Button' />
<br>
<select style="display: none;" id='List' name='List'/>
</form>

$("#testbtn").click(function() {
   $('#List').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apQYD/1/

Answer (score 4):

Change:

`<select style="visibility:hidden" id='List' name='List'/>
</form>`

To:

`<select style="display:none" id='List' name='List'/>
</form>`

`jQuery.toggle` modifies the `display` CSS property

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `visibility:hidden` in your inline style. Use `display:none` instead.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, toggle() relies on the display property, not the visibility one.

Try setting display:none instead of visibility:hidden.

```
<select style="display:none" id='List' name='List'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** mention clearly that

The `display` property is saved and restored as needed. If an element has a `display` value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

show i suggest another way to use class and remove `style=""` from `select`

css :

```
   .hide { display: none };
```

jQuery:

```
$("#testbtn").click(function() {
   $('#List').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/auFYf/)**